# Show that , $p=2m+1$ is prime if an only if $(-1)^m(m!)^2\equiv -1(\mod p)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

i start by Wilson's theorem  $$(p-1)!\equiv -1 (\mod p)$$
then $$2(m!)\equiv -1(\mod p)$$ 
now how we can continue ?

Comment: $(2m)! \equiv -1 \bmod p$, and $(2m)!    \equiv (\prod_{k=1}^m k) (\prod_{k=1}^m (p-k)) \equiv (\prod_{k=1}^m k) (\prod_{k=1}^m (-k)) \equiv (m!)^2 (-1)^m \bmod p$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(p-1)! = (1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot...m)\cdot((p-m)\cdot(p-(m-1))\cdot...\cdot(p-1)) = m!\cdot (-1)^m\cdot m! = (-1)^m (m!)^2$

Answer (score 1):

When you expand the product defining the factorial $(2m)!\pmod p$, you can replace half of the numbers by their opposites, more precisely those from $m+1$ to $2m$:
\begin{align*}(2m)!& \equiv1 \cdot 2\cdots m\cdot (m+1)\cdots 2m \pmod p\\
& \equiv 1\cdots m\cdot (m+1-2m-1)\cdot (m+2-2m-1)\cdots (2m-2m-1)\pmod p\\
& \equiv 1\cdots m \cdot m \cdots 1 \cdot (-1)^m\pmod p \\
& \equiv 1\cdots m\cdot (-m)\cdot (-(m-1))\cdots (-1)\pmod p \\ & \equiv (m!)^2(-1)^m\pmod p.\end{align*}